# How can i use ImageFetcher(iosched) with ActionBarSherlock + mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview, actionbarsherlock, iosched

I'm using the version of ActionBarSherlock which allows me to use ActionBarSherlock + MapView.
Now, i'm trying to show a mapview and a listview, but the listview has some items with url images. I wan to use the ImageFetcher of iosched, but the method getImageFetcher (of iosched) just allows the type FragmentActivity.

What can i do in this case??
Is there anyway to cast from Activity to FragmentActivity??
Or is there any other solution??

Regards

Comment: You have the source code right? You can change the source code of ImageFetcher in iosched, to satisfy you're needs. you can pull it from github:
https://github.com/jwang/iosched

Fork it, and adjust to needs

Comment: Well, my question was because i didn't know where should i start. Is there any implementation using Activity?

Comment: Start with changing the method you are calling, there you change it to Activity. Try to build and change what is faling step by step to get it working again.